# tf.matmul doesn't works as expected

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

i try to write and (logic operation) in tensor flow , there are two inputs and two weights multiply them to get one number and add this number to bias, my problem in matmul a send X (input) and W (weight) to method in shape .
[[1],
[1]] 
for X (vertical), and [0.49900547 , 0.49900547] for W (horizontal) to get one number as result but it's give me two numbers , how i can make is multiply right ??
this is my code >>

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy
rng = numpy.random

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 2000
display_step = 50

# Training Data
train_X = numpy.asarray([[[1.0],[1.0]],[[1.0],[0.0]],[[0.0],[1.0]],[[0.0],[0.0]]])
train_Y = numpy.asarray([1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0])
n_samples = train_X.shape[0]

# tf Graph Input
X = tf.placeholder("float",[2,1],name="inputarr")
Y = tf.placeholder("float",name = "outputarr")

# Create Model

# Set model weights
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,2]), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="bias")

# Construct a linear model
activation = tf.add(tf.matmul(X,W), b)
mulres = tf.matmul(X,W)

# Minimize the squared errors
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(activation-Y, 2))/(2*n_samples) #L2 loss
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost) #Gradient descent

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Fit all training data
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        for (x, y) in zip(train_X, train_Y):
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})

        #Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print "Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1),  \
                "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b) , "x= ",x," y =", y," result :",sess.run(mulres,feed_dict={X: x})

    print "Optimization Finished!"
    print  "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b), '\n'


    # Testing example, as requested (Issue #2)
    test_X = numpy.asarray([[1.0,0.0]])
    test_Y = numpy.asarray([0])

    for x, y in zip(train_X, train_Y):
        print "x: ",x,"y: ",y
        print "Testing... (L2 loss Comparison)","result :",sess.run(mulres, feed_dict={X: x})
        print sess.run(tf.matmul(X, W),feed_dict={X: x})
        print "result :"
        predict = sess.run(activation,feed_dict={X: x})
        print predict
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with standard matrix multiplication, if `A` has shape `[m, k]`, and `B` has shape `[k, n]`, then `tf.matmul(A, B)` has shape `[m, n]` (`m` rows, `n` columns in the order TensorFlow uses).

In your program, you are computing `tf.matmul(X, W)`. `X` is defined to be a placeholder with shape `[2, 1]`; `W` is defined to be variable initialized to a `[1, 2]` matrix of zeros. As a result, `mulres = tf.matmul(X, W)` will have shape `[2, 2]`, which is what is printed (`result: ...`) when I run your code locally.

If you want to define a hidden layer with a single output, the change is simple:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,2]), name="weight")
```

...should be replaced with:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, 1]), name="weight")
```

(Indeed, initializing your weights to `tf.zeros` will prevent it from training, because all of the input elements will get the same gradient in backpropagation. Instead, you should initialize them randomly, for example using:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, 1], stddev=0.5), name="weight")
```

This will enable the network to learn different values for each component of the weight.)

Answer (score 2):

`matmul` operates directly on the tensors which in your case have 2 rows and 1 column.

There is an argument in `matmul` to transpose either entry like:

```
matmul(X, W, transpose_a=True)
```

You can check out the docs here: [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#matmul)